# Theoretical variance of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

$W_1$ and $W_2$ would be $0$ since by using the fact that $E(X_1) - E(X_2)$ this gives us $0$?

Comment: That is already true by linearity of expectation. You only thing you need for that is that the means exist. Normality is not needed for that.

Comment: Okay, the question asks me to consider solving these problems using matrix operations. That is what is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation operator is linear, hence $\mathbb{E}\sum X_i = \sum \mathbb{E}X_i$. For the variance use the covariance between each pair, i.e., 
$$
\operatorname{var}(\sum X_i) = \sum \operatorname{var}(X_i) + 2 \sum_{i>j}\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_j).
$$

In matrix:

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3) ^ T $ and $ c_1 = (1, -1, 0) ^ T $ and $c_2 = (1, 1, -2) ^ T$. Then, $W_1 = c_1 ^ T X$ and $W_2 = c_2 ^ T X$, as such 
$$
\mathbb{E}[W_1] = c_1 ^ T \mathbb{E} X = c_1 ^ T \underline{\mu} = \mu - \mu=0.
$$
where $\underline{\mu} = (\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3) ^ T $. And for the variance
$$
\mathbb{V}(W_1) = c_1 ^ T\Sigma_{X}c_1 \, ,
$$
where $\operatorname{var}(X) = \Sigma_X \in \mathcal{M}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$. Same is true for $W_2$.

Comment: how would I solve this using matrix operations?

Comment: See the edited answer pls

Comment: so then is my theoretical mean for $W_1$ and $W_2$ equal to $0$?

Comment: I am also getting that my covariance for $X_1 - X_2$ is $0$ since it is a random sample and the observations are independent. My variance for $W_1$ is therefore 2$σ^2$

Comment: 1) Theoretical mean - yes. 2) Variance - If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then you are right.

Comment: what about the variance for $W_2$, I am not very familiar with the notation that you have used in your answer ( when you describe the calculation of the variance)

Comment: It is the standard matrix notation.. Assuming mutual independence, you have $ Var(W_2) = \sigma^2 + \sigma  ^ 2 + 2^2 \sigma^2$.

Comment: and so if we had $W_3 = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 - 3X_4$ then the variance for that, assuming mutual independence would be $12σ^2$?

Comment: Yes, you are right